# What expression do I need to use regex on this character in Java? |

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Simple question, yet nothing works for me. I'm trying to split a String by using this character | (yeah the straight stick thingy)

But instead, it splits my entire string into single characters. What is the regex for this character?

"|", or "\|", or "\p|" all don't work for some reason.

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the backslash. Please try `"\\|"`.

Answer (score 3):

This works without issues for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "apples|bananas|oranges";
    for (String string : s.split("\\|")) {
        System.err.println(string);
    }
}
```

I get

```
apples
bananas
oranges
```

Comment: Why do you need `IOException`? You need `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException` instead.

Comment: Mucho gracias senior! haha seriously that did the trick for me immediately, thanks mate!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad sorry, it's a leftover of another attempt I did for another question. I tend to reuse over and over the same dummy class. I will remove it as it is indeed not needed. The other exception is useless in this case since the pattern is valid

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it twice like `\\|` since `|` is a special character in both Java and regular expression.

Comment: Do you mean \ is a special character? The reason you need \\ is so the Java compiler doesn't interpret the regex as an escape sequence.